# USB GSM modem random disconnects on debian 10

Tags: debian, connection, modem, gsm, pppd

I'm trying to build a tiny (A20-based) server which should connect to internet (GSM) automatically and stay connected permantently. My setup is:

hardware:

```
Board: Olimex A20 OlinuXino-Lime2
GSM modem: USB HSDPA (https://www.olimex.com/Products/USB-Modules/MOD-USB3G/)
```

software:

```
debian 10
pppd
pppconfig (pon/poff)
usbmodeswitch
```

After boot, the modem is detected and modeswitched to Modem correctly (Bus 004 Device 004: ID **12d1:1001** Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E161/E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem) and /dev/ttyUSB0-2 are defined.

I've set up a systemd unit which starts pppd after ttyUSB0 becomes available and connects correctly to the GSM provider:

```
Jun 14 23:22:13 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 systemd[1]: Starting pppd daemon on /dev/ttyUSB0...
Jun 14 23:22:13 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 systemd[1]: Started pppd daemon on /dev/ttyUSB0.
Jun 14 23:22:13 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Jun 14 23:22:26 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/keepgo finished (pid 871), status = 0x5
Jun 14 23:22:26 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Connect script failed
Jun 14 23:22:59 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/keepgo finished (pid 971), status = 0x5
Jun 14 23:22:59 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Connect script failed
Jun 14 23:23:33 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/keepgo finished (pid 992), status = 0x0
Jun 14 23:23:33 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Serial connection established.
Jun 14 23:23:33 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: using channel 1
Jun 14 23:23:33 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 14 23:23:33 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc63c6af6> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x24d918f4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x24d918f4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc63c6af6> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x1 magic=0x24d918f4]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <00000000000000000000000000000000>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <7dacccc151c57331186e8771b0dccfb4>, name = "ppp"]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 ""]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x2 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]
Jun 14 23:23:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
Jun 14 23:23:35 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
Jun 14 23:23:35 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x0]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x0 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <addr 10.136.211.206> <ms-dns1 80.58.61.250> <ms-dns2 80.58.61.254>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 10.136.211.206> <ms-dns1 80.58.61.250> <ms-dns2 80.58.61.254>]
Jun 14 23:23:36 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x5 <addr 10.136.211.206> <ms-dns1 80.58.61.250> <ms-dns2 80.58.61.254>]
Jun 14 23:23:37 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Jun 14 23:23:37 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1]
Jun 14 23:23:37 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Jun 14 23:23:38 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: local  IP address 10.136.211.206
Jun 14 23:23:38 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Jun 14 23:23:38 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: primary   DNS address 80.58.61.250
Jun 14 23:23:38 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: secondary DNS address 80.58.61.254
Jun 14 23:23:38 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 1004)
Jun 14 23:23:38 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 1004), status = 0x0
Jun 14 23:24:04 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x1 magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 14 23:24:04 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x1 magic=0x24d918f4 c6 3c 6a f6]
Jun 14 23:24:34 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x2 magic=0xc63c6af6]
...
```

The connection provides access to the internet and stays stable until after about 6-7 hours. Then suddenly the connection is lost with the following log entries:

```
...    
Jun 15 06:10:21 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x2d magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 15 06:10:21 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x2d magic=0x24d918f4 c6 3c 6a f6]
Jun 15 06:10:51 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x2e magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 15 06:10:51 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x2e magic=0x24d918f4 c6 3c 6a f6]
Jun 15 06:11:21 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x2f magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 15 06:11:51 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x30 magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 15 06:12:21 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x31 magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 15 06:12:52 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x32 magic=0xc63c6af6]
Jun 15 06:13:22 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: No response to 4 echo-requests
Jun 15 06:13:22 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Serial link appears to be disconnected.
Jun 15 06:13:22 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Connect time 409.8 minutes.
Jun 15 06:13:22 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Sent 1067449 bytes, received 7513038 bytes.
Jun 15 06:13:22 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-down started (pid 1938)
Jun 15 06:13:22 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "Peer not responding"]
Jun 15 06:13:22 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-down finished (pid 1938), status = 0x0
Jun 15 06:13:25 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "Peer not responding"]
Jun 15 06:13:28 A20-OLinuXino-HA-001 pppd[870]: Connection terminated.
```

After stopping the connection there is no way to start it up again other than rebooting the system. I've tried poff, killall -9 pppd before trying to restart the connection (pon). Attempts to restart fail with the message: Device ttyUSB0 is locked by pid xxxx (which appears to be pppd)

My /etc/ppp/peers/provider (generated by pppconfig) is:

```
hide-password 
noauth
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/MyProvider"
debug
/dev/ttyUSB0
460800
defaultroute
noipdefault 
user "ppp"
remotename xxxx
ipparam xxxx

persist
usepeerdns
```

I'm lost, have tried quite some things (even a complete rebuild of the server) to no avail. I would highly appreciate any help to get this solved.

Mike

[This question was also asked on Stackoverflow, but no responses there]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a similar event occurs with a certain modem device I was using, however, my setup is very different from yours.

Primary point of error was the system board overheating which caused the port with the USB connection to disconnect and reconnect at random times (during power cycles mostly).

On the reconnect loop, there was an attempt by the system to update the USB device drivers online. But the loss of internet connectivity resulted in the failed update attempt.
Which in turn led to a failure in registering the device on the system upon reconnecting.

I've disabled automatic attempts to update device drivers online to see if this fixes the issue.

Here is a link on [how to disable automatic updates on Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/how-to-disable-automatic-update-ubuntu).
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/how-to-disable-automatic-update-ubuntu